# HTTP GET request not being answered on other country

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, embedded, lwip

I have one embedded device which is sending HTTP GET request from India to web server located at Spain to download file and it is perfectly working in India. My device can download file.

But when I give my binary to friend at Spain which have the same embedded device, his device can not download the file from web server.

My mind is now blank after searching on this issue. How can two same device with same firmware with same server behaves differently.

Note that device at Spain can ping the server and also downloads the small files (around 3-4KB). But it can not download larger file around (100KB).

I don't know what can be the issue.

Comment: Can you test the same GET request from desktop in Spain? Is the device using wired ethernet or perhaps mobile/3G?

Comment: Yes the same GET request from other device and browser is responded.And the device is using wired ethernet. We are using SPI to ethernet module.

Comment: Maybe different OS/kernel version/linbraries version on the Spain device?

Comment: No we are using controlled with lwip stack in it. And we both are using the same firmware.

Comment: The client device is the same, the server is the same, what is different is _the network between the 2_. Two things: 1/ I'd do a wireshark capture of the device to/from traffic if possible, and 2/ Your friend should try the exact same HTTP request, using the same network (example: maybe wifi, to DSL router, then his internet provider network), from his PC. Does it work? If not, again, wireshark (on his PC).

Comment: Does not sound like a software issue to me; more likely a network infrastructure issue - not a question for SO, and unanswerable in any case from the information given.

Comment: Yes Request from PC works. Note We are using same HTTP requests in both device. We are using HTTP fetcher c library in our code. We debugged our code and found that we are getting select timeout when try to download 100 kb file.